# need some insight with maya python basics

Tags: python, maya

I came across this script and just wanted it broken down even more for my understanding:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

targetCurve = 'curve1' # Curve to put clusters on

curveCVs = cmds.ls('{0}.cv[:]'.format(targetCurve), fl = True) # Get all cvs from curve

if curveCVs: # Check if we found any cvs


for cv in curveCVs:
    print 'Creating {0}'.format(cv)
    cmds.cluster(cv) # Create cluster on a cv
```

Is `cmds.ls('{0}.cv[:]` to get the points of the curve? Also what does `.format(targetCurve), fl = True)` mean? What is the `fl = true`?

Comment: You need to learn the basic syntax first. See https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: You might want to learn about strings in python. Here are some very good references: https://pyformat.info and  https://realpython.com/python-f-strings

Answer (score 0):

`.format` [is a native string method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp) that let's you concatenate values together into one string.

It's similar to doing `targetCurve + '.cv[:]'`.

To refer to a curve's cv you can use square brackets with a number inside: `'curve1.cv[0]'`, which will refer to `"curve1"`'s cv at index 0. You can even group multiple cvs like this: `'curve1.cv[0:3]'` and that's completely valid. And if you simply provide a colon `'curve1.cv[:]'` it's a short-handed way to refer to *all* cvs from the curve.

In your code sample, it's getting all cvs from `targetCurve`. `fl = True` is the flatten parameter for the `cmds.ls` command. Without it, the output may group cvs together like my example above, `'curve1.cv[0:3]'`. But with flatten, it forces the output to have a result for every cv: `['curve1.cv[0]', 'curve1.cv[1]', 'curve1.cv[2]']`

So in short, it's collecting all cvs from `"curve1"` and using flatten to force the output to not be grouped. If it finds any cvs, it loops through the results and creates a cluster with each cv.

If you need more info then you should check out [Maya's Python commands documentation](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2019/ENU/?guid=__CommandsPython_index_html) as it's actually pretty decent.

Comment: Ahhh brilliant, thank you very much, this really helps understand it more! feel like you've gone beyond what i asked for so much appreciated :)

Comment: No problem. If this has resolved your issue then consider accepting this answer so others know it's been solved.